# Why isn't a closure in @State array property triggering state change?

Tags: swift, swiftui

A `test` view has @State `showTitle`, `title` and `items` where the `title` value text is controlled by a closure assigned to a CTA `show title`.

When the `showTitle` state changes, the value presented in the body Content of `test` view changes accordingly:

```
Text({ self.showTitle ? "Yes, showTitle!" : "No, showTitle!" }())
```

While the case where the `closure` is a value in the array `items` does not change. Why isn't the closure triggering the title state?

```
NestedView(title: $0.title())
```

I've done tests with both Foobar as `Struct` and `Class`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Foobar: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var title: () -> String

    init (title: @escaping () -> String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

struct test: View {
    @State var showTitle: Bool = true
    @State var title: String
    @State var items: [Foobar]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                Text("Case 1")
                Text({ self.showTitle ? "Yes, showTitle!" : "No, showTitle!" }())
            }
            Group {
                Text("Case 2")
                ForEach (self.items, id: \.id) {
                    NestedView(title: $0.title())
                }
            }
            Button("show title") {
                print("show title cb")
                self.showTitle.toggle()
            }
        }.onAppear {
            let data = ["hello", "world", "test"]
            for title in data {
                self.items.append(Foobar(title: { self.showTitle ? title : "n/a" }))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NestedView: View {
    var title: String
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(title)")
    }
}
```

What's expected is that "Case 2" to have a similar side-effect we have in "Case 1" that should display "n/a" on `showTitle` toggle.

Output:

[image]

Comment: I don't see where you think you are changing a `@State` variable that is a closure. Can you be more explicit about which line you think does this and what you expect to happen?

Comment: Hi @matt, yes that's the "NestedView(title: $0.title())", the title() call, of "                self.items.append(Foobar(title: { self.showTitle ? title : "n/a" }))"

Comment: I don't get it. Is it that you think that changing your State `title` would somehow swing around and change the `title` already inside the Foobars?

Comment: Not, but when `showTitle.toggle()`, to see a similar side-effect I have in "Case 1"; this is to change the title text to "n/a" for "Case 2"

Comment: OK, that's clear. Well, so you think changing your State `showTitle` is somehow going to swing around and change what's in an already existing Foobar. That's not going to happen; the choice of Foobar is already made. If you wanted to change what Foobar you've got, you'd say `something = self.showTitle? Foobar(title: title) : Foobar(title:"n/a")`.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time! I thought about this pattern because I expected the closure to capture and store the reference of `self.showTitle`, which is mutable and controlled by the CTA "show title"; finally, have the same side-effect I get in the "Case 1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I understand, the reason why the initial code does not work is related to the showTitle property that is passed to the Array and holds a copy of the value

You were right to blame the closure capturing the value at the `onAppear` time. Basically due to this, SwiftUI doesn't know to refresh the list when the `showTitle` value changes, as there's no `Binding` involved that SwiftUI can use to know when to re-render the list.

I can provide two alternative solutions, that don't require another class just to hold the bool value. Both solutions involve communicating to SwiftUI that you need the `showTitle` binding to refresh the titles.

1. Don't use a closure for `title`, defer the title computation to the list builder:

```swift
struct Foobar: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var title: String

    init (title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }    
}

...

ForEach (self.items, id: \.id) {
    NestedView(title: self.showTitle ? $0.title : "n/a" )
}

...

.onAppear {
    let data = ["hello", "world", "test"]
    self.items = data.map { Foobar(title: $0) }
}
```

2. Convert the title closure to a `(Binding<Bool>) -> String` one, inject the `$showTitle` binding from the view:

```swift
struct Foobar: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var title: ((Binding<Bool>) -> String)
    
    init (title: @escaping (Binding<Bool>) -> String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

...

ForEach (self.items, id: \.id) {
    // here we pass the $showTitle binding, thus SwiftUI knows to re-render
    // the view when the binding value is updated
    NestedView(title: $0.title(self.$showTitle))
}

...

.onAppear {
    let data = ["hello", "world", "test"]
    self.items = data.map { Foobar(title: { $0.wrappedValue ? title : "n/a" })) }
}
```

Personally, I'd go with the first solution, since it better transmit the intent.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the reason why the initial code does not work is related to the `showTitle` property that is passed to the Array and holds a copy of the `value` (creates a unique copy of the data).

I did think @State would make it controllable and mutable, and the `closure` would capture and store the reference (create a shared instance). In other words, to have had a `reference`, instead of a copied `value`! Feel free to correct me, if that's not the case, but that's what it looks like based on my analysis.

With that being said, I kept the initial thought process, I still want to pass a `closure` to the Array and have the state changes propagated, cause side-effects, accordingly to any references to it!

So, I've used the same pattern but instead of relying on a primitive type for `showTitle` `Bool`, created a `Class` that conforms to the protocol `ObservableObject`: since `Classes` are `reference types`.

So, let's have a look and see how this worked out:

```
import SwiftUI

class MyOption: ObservableObject {
    @Published var option: Bool = false        
}

struct Foobar: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var title: () -> String

    init (title: @escaping () -> String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

struct test: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var showTitle: MyOption
    @State var title: String
    @State var items: [Foobar]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                Text("Case 1")
                Text(self.showTitle.option ? "Yes, showTitle!" : "No, showTitle!")
            }
            Group {
                Text("Case 2")
                ForEach (self.items, id: \.id) {
                    NestedView(title: $0.title())
                }
            }
            Button("show title") {
                print("show title cb")
                self.showTitle.option.toggle()
                print("self.showTitle.option: ", self.showTitle.option)
            }
        }.onAppear {
            let data = ["hello", "world", "test"]
            for title in data {
                self.items.append(Foobar(title: { self.showTitle.option ? title : "n/a" }))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NestedView: View {
    var title: String
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(title)")
    }
}
```

The result as expected:

[image]